# Add username into another table while creating a new Oracle user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I am creating a simple application where I am using a Servlet and JDBC to create users.

Is there any way I can use a trigger to insert the username into another table when the Oracle user is created with:

```
create user xyz ......
```

Once this query executes successfully, it inserts the user information in the `DBA_USERS` table.

I want the username to also be inserted into another table. Should I add it to that other table manually through JDBC, or can I create a trigger to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [a system trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#BABHEFGE) based on the `create user` DDL (but *not* a DML trigger on the `dba_users` view - you can't do that anyway, but don't even think about trying to do anything based on the data dictionary). But you wouldn't really have any way for that to know if the user being created is actually an application user - you'd be assuming any user added to the DB could *only* be related to your application.

Since you have to take other steps anyway - such as granting roles and/or privileges, maybe adding other application security data, etc., it probably makes more sense to do the table insert manually.

It may even make more sense to put all the user-creation code into a stored (and probably packaged) procedure, and just call that over JDBC; the downside of that is that the `create user` and any other DDL would need to be executed from within the procedure as dynamic SQL. Any of your own table inserts would be together though, and you'd only have that single JDBC call to make.

You can also have other procedures to modify and delete users.

Something to bear in mind, however you do it, is that DDL implicitly commits. Not necessarily a problem, just something to be aware of, so you can order the steps in a recoverable way.